# AJAX request with jQuery and PHP always return an JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I'm doing a validation with PHP doing AJAX request when user submit the information, But I have a problem because when I make the AJAX request it throws me an error when converting the JSON thrown by the PHP, because it tells me the following error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON

This appears when I try to convert the response to a Javascript object with the following line.

var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);

But if I try without convert it, it's works with:

var jsonData = response;

I understand that PHP has to return a JSON in response, not an object.

The request ajax:

```
let nombre = $nombre.value.trim();
        let apellidos = $apellidos.value.trim();
        let correo = $correo.value.trim();
        let telefono = $telefono.value.trim();
        
        //
        $.ajax({
            
            url: '../includes/email-check.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {nombre, apellidos, correo, telefono},
            success: function(response){

                var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log(jsonData);

                if(jsonData.email === true && jsonData.phone === true){
                    $formInput.submit();
                }else{
                    if(jsonData.email === false)
                        showError($correo, "El correo ya existe, ingresa otro.");
                    if(jsonData.phone === false)
                        showError($telefono, "El teléfono ya existe, ingresa otro.");
                }   
            },
            
            error: function(jqXHR,textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.error("AJAX Error:",textStatus,errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

and PHP code:

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . "../db.php";

    //we get the data that was sent from the ajax request
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];


    if(!empty($correo) && !empty($telefono) && !empty($nombre) && !empty($apellidos)){

        $text = "/^[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚäëïöüÄËÏÖÜàèìòùÀÈÌÒÙ\s]+$/";

        $message = [
            "name" => true,
            "lastnames" => true,
            "email" => true,
            "phone" => true,
        ];
        //$telefono = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $telefono);
        

        if(strlen($nombre) < 3 || strlen($nombre) > 30 || !preg_match($text,$nombre))
            $message["name"] = false;
        
        if(strlen($apellidos) < 5 || strlen($apellidos)>60 || !preg_match($text,$apellidos))
            $message["lastnames"] = false;
        


        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM socio WHERE correo = :email OR telefono = :telephone");
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $correo);
        $stmt->bindParam(':telephone', $telefono);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt -> setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $result = ($stmt -> fetchAll());
        
        if(!empty($result)){
            foreach($result as $row){
                if($row["correo"] === $correo)
                    $message["email"] = false;
                elseif ($row["telefono"] === $telefono)
                    $message["phone"] = false;
            }
        }

        //Convert PHP data into the JSON format
    
        Header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF8');
        echo json_encode($message);

    }
```

If i try with:

var jsonData = response;

it's works but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt you should look at the documentation. You can see that [jQuery.ajax Docs](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/) states that json is automatically parsed.

---

**converters** (default: `{"* text": window.String, "text html": true, "text json": jQuery.parseJSON, "text xml": jQuery.parseXML}`)
Type: [PlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject)

An object containing dataType-to-dataType converters. Each converter's value is a function that returns the transformed value of the response. (version added: [1.5](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.5/))

---

Comment: Thank you very much, now I will check documentation for things like this, with your answer I understood what was happening.